# How to loop through an object array and get object values in for loop using typescript

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to get the values of object keys in the array. but getting **property doesn't exists on type unknown** here is my code

```
  const getDataPrinted: any = () => {
    let a = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      a =
        a +
        `<div style = "padding-top:250px; padding-left: 60px"> <h1> STOCK#: ${data[i].stock //**getting error here**} </br> VIN#: ${32332} </br> MSRP: ${3233} </br></br> ${2022} ${'Kia'} ${'Forte'} </h1> </br></br> <h1 style = "font-size: 40px"> ${'Added Mark-Up: $0:00'} </br> Nil </h1> </div><p style="page-break-after: always"></p>`
    }
    return a
  }
```

any solution for this? I'm new to typescript.

Comment: The problem is that TypeScript doesn't know what type `data[i]` is, as far as it knows the type is `unknown`, and there are no properties or methods that you can use on type `unknown`. You haven't shown what the type of `data` is or where it comes from, but if you give it a type that has a `stock` property, that code will work. (That said, I'd use `for-of` rather than `for`, and you have several substitutions with literals in them like `$(32332}` and `${'Kia'}` -- there's no reason to do that, just use the literal text.)

Comment: I have given type [] as any to data, data is an array having objects, and has different key, value pairs. stock is one of them. I have to populate stock and some other data too which is static right now.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the error by accessing like data[i]['stock']